# Special Characters in Xml

Tags: xml, special-characters

I have to create an Xml file starting from a Mysql database. I'm using a php script to genere the xml file.
Here the part of php code I am using to generate my xml file:

```
// create a new XML document
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// create root node
$root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('rss'));
$root->setAttribute('version', '2.0');
$root->setAttribute('encoding', 'UTF-8');

// create children
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   // add node for each row
  $occ = $doc->createElement('item');
  $occ = $channelNode->appendChild($occ);


  // add a child node for each field

  foreach ($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {


        if($fieldname =='description')   {

          $newcdata=$doc->createCDATASection($fieldvalue);
          $child = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
          $child = $occ->appendChild($child);
          $value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
          $value = $child->appendChild($newcdata);
        }
        else {
          $child = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
          $child = $occ->appendChild($child);
          $value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
          $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }



      } // foreach

} // while
```

This program is working well. The problem occurs where there are special Characters into the database to insert into the XML file, in this case i am trying to insert data using `CDATA` but it is not working. So, how can I insert spcecial Characters into an Xml file?

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description. What happens? And what “special characters” is this about?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to insert [certain characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) into an XML document. The work-around is for both the sender and receiver to agree on how they will be encoded. Common options include Base64 and Ascii85.

It might also be possible to do simple character substitution such as using the Unicode control pictures. For example, ␀ [\u2400](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2400/index.htm) for \0 and ␇ [\u2407](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2407/index.htm) for \b. That keeps it human readable but still would require the sender and receiver to agree.